# React/Firebase error "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: (0 , _firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.default) is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

Trying to implement user authentication using firebase into my react app. I have a firebase.js file where the register/login/logout functions are defined and then imported into the login/register screens. I don't have any errors until I actually try to register a user, then I get the error in the title.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import register from "../firebase";
import "../css/RegisterScreen.css";

function RegisterScreen() {

  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (password == '') {
        setError("Empty Password");
    } else {
        setEmail("");
        setPassword("");
        const res = await register(email, password);
        if (res.error) setError(res.error)
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="register">
        <h2>Sign Up</h2>
        <div className="registerContainer">
            {error ? <div>{error}</div>: null}
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input 
                    type="email"
                    className="registerBox" 
                    value={email}
                    placeholder="Email Address"
                    onChange={(event) => {
                        setEmail(event.target.value);
                    }}
                />
                <input 
                    type="password" 
                    className="registerBox" 
                    value={password}
                    placeholder="Password"
                    onChange={(event) => {
                        setPassword(event.target.value);
                    }}
                />
                <button 
                    className="registerButton"
                    type="submit">
                    Register
                </button>
            </form>
            <div>
                Already registered? <Link to="/login">Login</Link>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default RegisterScreen
```

This line of code in particular is where the error occurs

```
        const res = await register(email, password);
```

Here is the firebase.js file and the register function created there

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import {
     getAuth,
     createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
     signInWithEmailAndPassword,
     signOut,
 } from "firebase/auth";
 import {
     getFirestore,
     addDoc,
     collection
 } from "firebase/firestore";

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);

const register = async (email, password) => {
    try {
        const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
        const user = userCredential.user;
        await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
            uid: user.uid,
            email: user.email,
        });
        return true
    } catch (error) {
        return {error: error.message}
    }
};

const login = async (email, password) => {
    try {
        const userCredential = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
        const user = userCredential.user;
        return true
    } catch (error) {
        return {error: error.message}
    }
};

const logOut = async() => {
    try {
        await signOut(auth)
        return true
    } catch (error) {
        return false
    }
};

export default {
    register,
    login,
    logOut,
    db,
    auth,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not exporting any function from `firebase.js` but trying to import `register` function. Instead try exporting the Firebase services and defining the function in the register screen or export the function itself. Try:

```
// firebase.js
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);

export { auth, db } // no default
```

```
import { auth } from "../firebase";

const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (password == '') {
    setError("Empty Password");
  } else {
    setEmail("");
    setPassword("");
    try {
      const userCredential = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
      const user = userCredential.user;
      await addDoc(collection(db, "users"), {
        uid: user.uid,
        email: user.email,
      });
      console.log("User created", user)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message)
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: sorry I did not add it, but I did do the exports at the bottom of firebase.js.

Comment: I changed the export default to export and now it works. Not sure why that made the difference. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @torreypines  can you please update your question with the exact code? Also then the import statement should be `import { register } from "../firebase"`.. notice the `{}` and also `export` only instead of `export default`